# How to create dynamic html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am creating an Electronic Book and in every page of it there is a JPEG file. I have 224 pages/pictures. Every picture is called from an HTML file. So i have 224 HTML files.

But i am wondering if there is a way to create those HTML files dynamically every time the user clicks on my Electronic Book. But the files must be created before the user visits the page. Also i am thinking that maybe there are Electronic Books with more pages/pictures (1000 for example). So in order to have statically so many HTML files it is better to create them dynamically when the user clicks and when the user leaves delete the HTML files.

So i am looking for an HTML constructor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There will be multiple users asking for the same Electronic Book ? So, there is no such thing as creating the html files and storing them physically for each user separately. 

Assuming you are storing the pictures on a server, you can use a server side language like PHP to create the html pages, one page at a time, on the fly, based on what was the page number created last. If you want it to work only the local machine,html, javascript/jquery should do.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use PHP? you'll have less html files than 224 pages.

Comment: Because of SEO , which depends on website performance in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is basically used for Static Contents.If u want to have dynamic content then pages must be dynamic and there must be source to provide data like database.You can generate html files using dynamic source like php.